# Date parsing error - Format from javadoc

Tags: java

I'm currently trying to parse a date, and I took the following example from the javadoc (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) :

Format : "EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"
Date : Wed, 4 Jul 2001 12:08:56 -0700

To parse this date I'm currently doing the following :

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z").parse("Wed, 4 Jul 2001 12:08:56 -0700")
```

But I get an exception

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed, 4 Jul 2001 12:08:56 -0700"

. What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed, 4 Jul 2001 12:08:56 -0700"

Comment: Could it be that `MMM` doesn't mean `Jul` that it could be expecting `07` ?

Comment: is -0700 correct, did you try it without it?

Comment: What's your locale? (print is with `System.out.println(Locale.getDefault())`). If you're let's say, in a French locale, then this english date won't be parseable.

Comment: without -0700 it doesn't work

Comment: My locale is fr_FR. Isn't there a workaround to parse it ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved :

I have to specify the locale, since the locale of my computer is not en_US :

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH).parse("Wed, 4 Jul 2001 12:08:56 -0700")
```