# Unparseable date: "2015, July 22, 00:30"

Tags: java, date

Somehow I am getting this error over and over again and have no idea why. This is my code:

```
Date parseDate() {
    String date = "2015, July 22, 00:30";
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy, MMM dd, HH:mm");
    try {
        return formatter.parse(date); // Here: Unparseable date: "2015, July 22, 00:30"
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Anybody has any idea why is this happening? How to solve it?

Comment: Works on my computer.

Comment: It works on my machine also.  What is your default Locale?

Comment: The code you have posted works under java 1.7 and 1.8. If that is user input are you sure that there's no unicode coming in?

Comment: I've tested your snippet here [link](http://goo.gl/o09Oox) with no thrown exceptions. You can try adding the locale like so `SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy, MMM dd, HH:mm", Locale.US);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can not parse String with Simple Date format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606397/can-not-parse-string-with-simple-date-format). And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16288295/642706). And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22323837/642706). And many more.

Comment: And why the down vote? Isn't this a legitimate question? The fact it may be duplicated does not invalidate the fact the error may happen. I usually look all over the internet for answers before posting a question here, and I did not see that other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a [Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) if your default locale has different names for month, weekdays and so on. Since you can simply add it to the [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat-java.lang.String-java.util.Locale-) you can use something like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy, MMM dd, HH:mm", Locale.US);
```

And btw: you don't need to use four *M* if you just like to [`parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-) the String. But you need to add the additional *M* if you like to [`format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format-java.util.Date-) a given `Date` object to a String.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the Month, you are using MMM rather than MMMMM

`SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy, MMMMM dd, HH:mm");`

Comment: I am copying your very same line of code, and it says the same `Unparseable date`. Any idea? My java version is 1.8_31 BTW. Compiling with Maven 3.2.3.

Comment: @JoeAlmore It appears Michele put 5 M's instead of 4!

Try just using 4.

Comment: @JoeAlmore, what is your locale?

Comment: It looks like 5 M's is what the Javadoc suggests for full month names  (see in the Example table) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: I already tried with M's from 1 to 10 and the same result. One thing I did was to remove the *"y"* of *July* and leave 3 M's, then it worked. But how is this possible?

Comment: May be due to the version of your JDK, what version are you running?

Comment: 3 M's is what is used for 3 character months like Jan, Feb .. Dec

Answer (score 0):

The month needs 4 M's not 3 so:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy, MMMM dd, HH:mm");
```

3 is the short form of the month name so "January" becomes "Jan" and so on...

Comment: Thanks for your answer but already tried that one. The same error.

Comment: Sorry then I have no idea what the problem is. I'm running it and it works fine. I have no idea what the rest of your code looks like but maybe make the method `public`.